# How to enable template slideshow to only specific pages

Tags: php, joomla, slideshow

So I am using this Joomla template Morecolor, which has a slideshow built-in. Is there a way I could program the slideshow to appear on the website on specific pages only?

Here is a screenshot in Joomla:

http://s23.postimg.org/qc82malnv/untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

Template providers should not have things like slideshows built into them unless they provide the ability to assign it to specific pages. Template are templates. Slideshows are extensions. The best way to get around you issue would be to disable the template slideshow and download a slideshow extension from here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-jquery-slideshow

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had this method in mind, but I was wondering if there is a easier way around it.

Comment: this is the easiest way. You could add an `if` statement into the index.php for your template, however if you install an update for the template, it will override the changes and you will have to add it again. That's one of the reason why editing core code for either templates or extensions is not recommended.

Comment: If you _really_ want to use your existing template and not switch to a 3rd party extension for your slideshow, there are things you could do, but you would be stuck on that version of your template forever, which isn't an ideal option.